# IE 8 shows video as small square in upper left corner

Tags: internet-explorer-8, video.js

I've searched for a couple of days now and can't seem to figure this out.

My video loads but it is the wrong size. It is a small square in the upper left of the player. Firefox and Chrome display the video correctly.  Autoplay is enabled, but the big play icon is displayed (and never disappears.) When Autoplay isn't used, the video will not play, even when the big play icon is clicked.

Also, when I try to open the vanilla video-js demo in IE8, only the poster image will load. Nothing happens when I click the image to play the demo video.

The green square in the upper left is my video:

[image: video-js_smallSquareVideo.png]
<sub>(source: [gonzalimation.com](http://gonzalimation.com/misc/video-js_smallSquareVideo.png))</sub>

Comment: Why are you using IE, let alone IE 8?

Comment: IE 8 doesn't support videos: https://www.caniuse.com/video